# Best practice in building outlook layout in asp.NET & telerik radpanelbar as a page arch?

Tags: user-controls, asp.net-ajax, telerik, panel

I am working on enterprise apps, I am using telerik controls to make life easier ;)
The layout of my application on the left [radpanelbar](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax-beta/panelbar/examples/functionality/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx) used for the navigation menu, on the right side is the content.

I want to make this navigation menu to navigate to a usercontrol (.ascx file) instead of a page (.aspx file)
The navigation control is in the master page.
I have multiple reasons to make this kind of navigation:

1. I have many user controls, and do not want to make pages (.aspx) as many user controls as I have.
2. Which is the most important I want to make this happen on the fly with out post pack (AJAX).

So please could any one tell about the best practice to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to load the navigation user control programmatically via AJAX when the user clicks a panelbar item. Still positioning this user control on the master page and loading it from the content page is quite odd to me and I personally do not approve it as a good architectural decision.

Comment: thanks Dick for answer my question, what is a good architectural Design for this to be implemented on like this UI Via AJAX ( a sample would be appreciated :) )